# how can I do versioned transaction with python_?

Tags: transactions, signature

https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py

I'm using this place, but I can't find how to do a versioned transaction. :(

Comment: It is not supported there, as you can see from this issue https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/issues/320 which it looks like you already commented on :-)